# Proving a property of a finite subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite subgroups of a group $A$, then $|XY| = \frac{|X||Y|}{|X \cap Y|}$.

I am not really sure how to even start this problem. It looks like something that would be not very difficult to solve, however, I must not be remembering some key point.

Comment: As Alex Becker showed in his answer, when you see such a problem, in which you have to compute the cardinality as a quotient of two cardinalities, you should try to come up with a surjective map.

Comment: M Turgeon is right, this is usually the easiest approach. It is even used to extend these notions to infinite sets.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $X\times Y\to XY$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$. This is clearly surjective. For any $xy\in XY$, we have $x'y'=xy$ iff $y'=({x'}^{-1}x)y$, so given any fixed $x'$ there is exactly one such $y'$ if $({x'}^{-1}x)y\in Y$, i.e. $x'\in X\cap Y$, and otherwise there is no such $y'$. Thus the number of preimages of each $xy\in XY$ is $|X\cap Y|$, so 
$$|XY|=\frac{|X\times Y|}{|X\cap Y|}=\frac{|X||Y|}{|X\cap Y|}$$